# Can't make UITableView appear under translucent navigation bar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to use a translucent navigation bar and want to put my table view (in a `UITableViewController`) under the navigation bar but without success.

I've been searching all over the web but I'm only finding help on how to push the content below the navigation bar which is exactly the opposite of what I'm trying to do.

I have Under Top Bars checked inside my storyboard.

Please help!

Comment: provide screenshot or code

Comment: Code doesn't matter with this case as this is a problem with the storyboard.
I don't understand why you would need a screenshot the UITableView just appears below the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO
```

in  `viewDidLoad` and then check

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but instead of doing it by code i set it in the storyboard on my UITableViewController

Comment: I can't use a custom bar tint color and make it translucent. The only thing that works is if I set the bar tint color to default i.e. making it black.